# How to append/concat 2 Pandas Dataframe with different columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

How to concat/append based on common column values?

I'm creating some dfs from some files, and I want to compile them.
The columns don't always match, but there will always be some common columns (I only know a few columns guaranteed to match, but there's a lot of columns, and I'd like to retain as much info as possible)

df1:

| Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| Jane | 2 |

df2:

| Extra1 | Extra2 | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | Bob | 2 |
| c | d | Nancy | 2 |

Desired output:

either this (doesn't matter of the order):

| Extra1 | Extra2 | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | Bob | 2 |
| c | d | Nancy | 2 |
| NULL | NULL | John | 1 |
| NULL | NULL | Jane | 2 |

Or this (doesn't matter of the order):

| Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| Jane | 2 |
| Bob | 2 |
| Nancy | 2 |

I've tried these, but doesn't get the result I want:

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df = df.set_index('Name').combine_first(df2.set_index('Name')).reset_index()
```

Thanks

Not sure why the tables aren't being formatted, it shows up fine in the preview

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'Jane'],'Status':[1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Extra1':['a','b'],'Extra2':['c','d'],'Name':['bob', 'nancy'],'Status':[2,2]})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Gives me

| Name | Status | Extra1 | Extra2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| Jane | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| bob | 2 | a | c |
| nancy | 2 | b | d |

Which looks to me like your desired output.

And your tables aren't formatted correctly because you need empty newlines between text and tables.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the tables formatting. `df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)` retrying this, assuming it matters, I had the order of the dfs in the [] the wrong way

Comment: hmm idk why, but pd.concat doesn't get the expected result for me:/